# How spring application internally call another normal servlet but hosted on the same tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

I am looking for a way for communication between spring boot servlet application and other normal java servlet hosted on the same tomcat,internally.I have a requirement to have this without user knowledge for security purpose.

Assume the spring application is running on say, myspringcontext & I am inside a controller within my spring application. At this time after doing some security check I want to call another tomcat servlet internally. say , a URL /authconext/normalservlet

I have an HTTP server infront of this tomcat, so /authconext/normalservlet
I could protect.

response.SendRedirect() I cannot use, since it will redirect through browser.

Comment: So, you want to send a HTTP request, from a Spring controller. See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#webmvc-client, or use any other HTTP client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply  I will make use of RestTemplate. Infact I was using RestTemplate in my project.. But due to a misunderstanding I did not try in this situation.

Comment: Have you suggested me to use WebClient which is non blocking? I cannot use RestTemplate.. I got this error HTTP Status 500 - Could not write JSON: Not available in non blocking mode; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: I will update my question since I am now using apache HttpClient..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send a HTTP request from springapplication to the "normal" servlet in another application you can send POST from the spring controller to
`localhost:8080/authconext/normalservlet/receivedata`
where receivedata is an endpoint of "normal"-servlet.
This method is not necessarily to be recommended. It would be better to combine both applications together, if possible.